# PHP - password_verify() returns false on correct password

Tags: php, hash, passwords, password-protection

`password_verify` is returning `false` for a correct password. To hash the password in another script, I used `password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` where it is then stored in the database.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$validated = true;
$usrEmail = "";
$usrPassword = "";

//Validate 'email':
if(!isset($_GET['email'])){
    $usrEmail = "";
}else{
    $usrEmail = $_GET['email'];
}

//Validate 'password':
if(!isset($_GET['password'])){
    $usrPassword = "";
}else{
    $usrPassword = $_GET['password'];
}

if($validated){
    //Send data to database:
    $response = sendRequest($GLOBALS['usrEmail'], $GLOBALS['usrPassword']);
    echo json_encode($response);
}else{
    //Send an error:
    $response = array('LOGGEDIN' => 'NO', 'STATUS' => 'VALIDATIONFAIL');
    echo json_encode($response);
}

//Make the request:
function sendRequest($email, $usrPassword){

    include('config.php');
    $sql = 'SELECT password
            FROM `users`
            WHERE email=?';

    $pdo = new PDO($connect_pdo, $User, $Password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    try {

        $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $array = array($email);
        $sth->execute($array);

        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
        $numrows = $sth->rowCount();

        $hashedPassword = '';
        if($numrows > 0){
            for ($ri = 0; $ri < $numrows; $ri++) {
                $row = $result[$ri];
                $hashedPassword = $row['password'];
            }

            $hashedPassword = substr( $hashedPassword, 0, 60 );
            if(password_verify($usrPassword, $hashedPassword)){
                return login($email, $hashedPassword);
            }else{
                return array("LOGGEDIN" => 'NO', "STATUS" => 'Password Mismatch');
            }
        }else{
            return array("LOGGEDIN" => 'NO', "STATUS" => 'Unknown Error');;
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I have looked at many different posts, both on Stack Overflow and on other sites and none of the solutions related to my problem.

Comment: Can an email address have more than one entry in the table? i.e. more than one password?

Comment: @Nick at this stage there is no UNIQUE constraint on the table but there is only one entry with this email address.

Comment: Ok, it's just the way your code is written it only compares the password against the last password in the table for a given user.

Comment: @Nick So I should add the UNIQUE constraint and see if taht works?

Comment: If there is only one entry for that email address then it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Nick OK - I did think that was the case, I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: how can you access your variable outside for loop ? i am not sure this is right code. print your `$hashedPassword` before if condition and check are you getting the value ?

Comment: @prakashtank I am able to access the variable. It prints the hashed password. I also tried with declaring `$hashedPassword` before the if statement and I get the same result.

Comment: Hey, @ChristopherLittlewood your code is working absolutely fine. The hash of the password is somewhere around 60 characters. So just check your password field in the database it should be varchar (60) or more than 60 characters.

Comment: @ChristopherLittlewood - A field of `varchar(255)` is recommended, so the method `password_hash()` can switch to other algorithms in future.

Comment: @ChristopherLittlewood : please go through this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610403/php-password-verify-not-working-with-database

Comment: @prakashtank I have added `$hashedPassword = substr( $hashedPassword, 0, 60 );` to no avail. (Added to my post above)

Comment: @DanishShaikh I have a field of `varchar(255) in my db.

Comment: What are the values of `$usrPassword` and `$hashedPassword`?  E.g. show us the output from `var_dump(bin2hex($userPassword), bin2hex($hashedPassword));`

Comment: @salathe the output is `string(16) "5465737431323334" string(120) "2432792431302431485a33385974586867537a4f68525632736c32587533316e59532e4e327969726c47677149382e342f32326c7975353666664775"`

Comment: You did something wrong to generate the password hash: the original pre-hash value is an empty string (or null, or something else that converts to an empty string). `password_hash("", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("salt" => "1HZ38YtXhgSzOhRV2sl2Xu"))` gives the same hash as you provided (see https://3v4l.org/BOB9q)

Comment: That did it, not sure what exactly did it but I played around with my `createAccount` page and was able to fix it. thanks