# Google Recaptcha error, logs in without completing puzzle but shows tick

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, recaptcha

I have built a log in system and I am adding google recaptcha for security. I am getting an error on this line: `$result = json_decode($url, TRUE);`

The error says;

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request.

This is my first time using `recaptcha` and I am not sure if this is a common mistake.

```
<?php

$secret = '*****';
$response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$remoteip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$captcha = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$response&remoteip=$remoteip");
$result = json_decode($url, TRUE);
$username;
$password;
$captcha;
if (isset($_POST['username']))
    $username = $_POST['username'];
if (isset($_POST['password']))
    $password = $_POST['password'];
if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']))
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
if (!$captcha) {
    echo '<p class="error-message">Please Complete The Captcha!</p>';
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6LfG-S8UAAAAAIqW1sBE31yMPyO4zeqOCgDzL1mA&response=" . $captcha . "&remote=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), true);
if ($response['success'] == false) {
    echo '<p class="error-message">Please Fill Captcha!</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p class="error-message2">Welcome</p>';
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $q = $handler->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?');
    $q->execute(array($username));
    $result = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($result !== false) {
        $hash_pwd = $result['password'];
        $hash = password_verify($password, $hash_pwd);

        if ($hash) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("location:index.php");
            return;
        } else {
            echo '<p class="error-message3"><br><br>You have ented an incorrect login!<br>Please try again</p>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: 400 means the request you sent is bad, have you sent all that was required?

Comment: @delboy1978uk, i have sent all the information google recommended on their site.

Comment: Aha! You are performing a `GET` request, not `POST`, which is what google wants - https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api-request

Comment: So, either perform a `cURL` request, or use a composer HTTP client package like Guzzle to do the cURL request for you

Comment: Yes @delboy1978uk, on which line?

Comment: oh really, how would i preform a curl? @delboy1978uk

Comment: Check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354633/curl-recaptcha-not-working-php

Comment: @delboy1978uk thank you

Comment: de nada senorita!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this really is your complete code:

It seems you are using `$url` (in the line `$result = ...`) without having initialized it before.

Additionally, I would expect that a variable with name `$url` contains an URL, and URLs are not in JSON format, so this raises some alarm signs. You eventually do not want to JSON-parse an URL, but instead parse what this URL returns when calling it.

Secondly, sometimes the line numbers within error messages or warnings are misleading. I highly doubt that the error you have mentioned (HTTP request failed) is related to `json_decode()`. `json_decode()`, as the name implies, just parses a string in JSON format, but does not load anything via HTTP.

So the error message probably comes from the line above ($captcha = `file_get_contents(...);`). I suppose that the URL you give there is wrong, or that Google refuses the request for another reason.

The first thing I would do is putting that URL into a variable and print it out (e.g. by using `error_log()`).

If that does not lead to the source of the problem, I would copy that URL (not from the code, but from the output produced by `error_log()`) and paste it directly into the address bar of a new browser window. If this yields the expected result (you should see Google's answer to the request in the browser window), the error is in your code. Otherwise, the error is in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
try {
  $ini = parse_ini_file("/var/www/admin.ini");
  $user = $ini['user'];
  $pass = $ini['pass'];
  $name = $ini['name'];
  $host = $ini['host'];
  $handler = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.'; dbname='.$name, $user, $pass);
  $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}   
catch(PDOException $e){
      error_log($e);
      echo $e->getMessage();
}
    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
      'secret' => '********',
      'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
    ],
  ]);  

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));

if (!$response->success) {
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $username = $_POST['username'];
       $password = $_POST['password'];
       $q = $handler->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?');
       $q->execute(array($username));
       $result = $q -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          if ($result !== false) {
               $hash_pwd = $result['password'];
               $hash = password_verify($password, $hash_pwd);
                if ($hash) {
                   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                   header("location:index.php");return;
               }
               else {echo '<p class="error-message3"><br><br>You have ented an incorrect login!<br>Please try again</p>';
                } 
          }
    }
}

?>
```